# Streaming API with logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, twitter-streaming-api

I'm trying to use logstash exec plugin to ingest the twitter stream into elastic. As the API endpoint gives a stream of tweets(decahose), exec plugin doesn't seem to be working. Are there any better ways to do with logstash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that 'pipe' input plugin works fine than the 'exec' plugin in logstash

```
 input {
  pipe {
    command => 'curl --compressed -v -u <<username>>:<<password>> "https://gnip-stream.twitter.com/stream/sample10/accounts/<<accountName>/publishers/twitter/<<env>>.json"'
    codec => "json"
  }
}
```